# How to get a working kubernetes container with nmcli?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, gitlab-ci-runner, nmcli

I fail to use `mcli` inside a kubernetes cluster while the same container works locally through `podman` .
For this I use a gitlab-runner into a kubernetes cluster.

```
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ ks-libvirt --help
Can't exec "nmcli": No such file or directory at (eval 61) line 149.
Can't open 'nmcli' with mode '-|': 'No such file or directory' at /usr/bin/ks-libvirt line 537
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

The gitlab-runner is configured with `privileged` and this volume is mounted `/var/run/dbus`
bellow a part of the configuration:

```
## Configure integrated Prometheus metrics exporter
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/monitoring/#configuration-of-the-metrics-http-server
metrics:
  enabled: true
  service:
    enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true

## Configuration for the Pods that that the runner launches for each new job
##
runners:
  ## Default container image to use for builds when none is specified
  ##
  image: rockylinux:8.5
  
  privileged: true
  tags: "privileged,large"
  runUntagged: false

  ## Configure environment variables that will be injected to the pods that are created while
  ## the build is running. These variables are passed as parameters, i.e. ,
  ## to  command.
  ##
  ## Note that  (see below) are only present in the runner pod, not the pods that are
  ## created for each build.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gexport NAMESPACE="gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-register"
  ##
  env:
    HOME: /tmp

  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        hostNetwork = true
        privileged = true
        # build container
        cpu_limit = "2"
        memory_limit = "5Gi"
        # service containers
        service_cpu_limit = "1"
        service_memory_limit = "1Gi"
        # helper container
        helper_cpu_limit = "1"
        helper_memory_limit = "1Gi"
      [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "var-dbus"
          host_path = "/var/run/dbus"
          mount_path = "/var/run/dbus"
          read_only = false
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "run-dbus"
          host_path = "/run/dbus"
          mount_path = "/run/dbus"
          read_only = false
```

While with `podman` + `root` + `privileged` + `--net host` that works

```
# podman  run --rm --name qcow --net host  --privileged  -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus -it localhost/fedora_qcow /bin/bash
...
[root@container /]# ks-libvirt --help
Usage:
    ks-libvirt [options] kickstart-file

    At the end of install, if the VM is not shut down with --off and the
    guest agent is not excluded with --noaddga, the script waits until the
    VM is up and an IPv4 address is configured; it will clean any previous
    SSH host keys for that IP and then print the IP, so if you have an SSH
    key defined, you can do:

            ssh -l root $(ks-libvirt kickstart-file)

Options:
    --addga | -a
            Add qemu-guest-agent to %packages; default is to do this, use
            --noaddga to disable. Without the agent, the hypvervisor cannot
            get the IP of the VM (or do other VM management).

    --anaconda | -A arguments
            Additional anaconda boot arguments

    --config | -C config
            Config file for defaults; default is $HOME/.virtinst.cf

    --cpu | -c count
            VM CPU cores; default is 1

    --disk | -d GB
            VM disk size in gigabytes; default is 6

    --disk2 GB
            VM second disk size in gigabytes; default is to not use a second
            disk (this is mostly just useful for testing kickstart RAID
            handling)

    --dns DNS-IPs
            Set the DNS server(s) (can be specified more than once for
            multiple servers); default: copy host DNS config when IPv4
            address is set

    --dumpks | -D
            Generate a modified kickstart file and dump to standard out
            (don't build VM)

    --gw IPv4-gateway
            Set the IPv4 gateway

    --hostname | -h FQDN
            Set the hostname; default is to not set unless network is set,
            then use the VM name

    --ip IPv4-address/mask
            Set the IPv4 address and netmask (in bits, e.g. 10.0.0.1/24);
            default is to try DHCP (if network needed)

    --iso | -i ISO
            ISO to boot from; default is pulled from KS or to use URL
            instead. Handles a local ISO file (will be uploaded to same pool
            as VM storage if needed), or pool/volume for an ISO already in a
            storage pool.

    --libvirt | -l URL
            Connection to libvirt; default is $VIRTSH_DEFAULT_CONNECT_UID or
            qemu:///system

    --mapfile | -m file
            URL map file to use different source repos. The format of the
            file is one entry per line with a pair of URLs separated by a
            space. The first URL is the original (which can be a mirrorlist
            or metalink) followed by a target URL to replace it with
            (mirrorlist/metalink are turned into direct url entries). The
            default is $HOME/.virtinst-map

    --name | -n name
            VM name; default is KS file name minus any leading "ks-"

    --net | -N interface
            Bridge network interface to attach to; default is interface with
            default route

    --off | -O
            Leave the VM off at the end of install

    --pool | -p pool
            Storage pool name; use pool default by default

    --os | -o OS
            OS name, used to set VM hardware config; default is autodetect

    --quiet | -q
            Be very quiet - only show errors and IP at end

    --ram | -r MB
            VM RAM size in megabytes; default is 2048 unless specified in
            the KS

    --screen | -s
            Open the VM console screen during install

    --secureboot | -B
            Enable Secure Boot (implies UEFI).

    --securepath [path]
            Specify the path to the Secure Boot loader/NVRAM files (default
            is /usr/share/edk2/ovmf)

    --serial | -S
            Add a serial console; default is to do this, use --noserial to
            disable

    --ssh   Add found SSH key(s) to the installed system; default is to do
            this, use --nossh to disable

    --tpm   Add TPM device

    --uefi | -u
            Use UEFI boot instead of BIOS

    --vdelete
            Delete an existing VM with the same name before creating new
            (NOTE: will not ask for confirmation!)

    --verbose | -v
            Be more verbose

    --virtinst | -V arguments
            Additional virt-install arguments (can be used more than once)
```